# Split() string except for certain character combination

Tags: c#

I want something like:

```
"aaaXaaaXaaaXaaaYXaaa".Split('X');
```

but want it to ignore 'YX'.

Of course I can simply loop and correct for it. But is there a built-in method for that?

Comment: Is it just `YX` specifically you want to ignore, or any capital letter before `X`?

Comment: I think Mark Byers' answer is the one you want then :)

Comment: @keyboardP Yeah. Something about that answer's rep gave me that impression. :)

Comment: @ispiro Don't always rely on high-rep users being right :p

Comment: @Rawling I didn't say 'answerer'. I said 'answer'. But you'd actually be right about that too.

Comment: If anyone reading this knows how to have multiple options for the first character (like WYZX YZWX ..) I'd like to know.

Comment: OK. Never mind. I think I found it: `(?<!WYZ|YZW)X`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with a negative lookbehind:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(s, "(?<!Y)X");
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/mqhEKN)

More information about lookarounds: [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to check how that works. (I don't mean 'if' it works. It's just that I don't have experience with Regex.)

Comment: OK, and what about if i want to keep `X` in result i.e. `aaaX, aaaX, aaaX, aaaYXaaa`?

Comment: @ispiro Why, where is the problem?

Comment: @Hamlet `(?<!YX)(?<=X)` should do it.